# Why Python works faster when declaring integer variable with int()?

Tags: python, performance, typing, dynamic-typing

While programming a algorithm that makes use of only using integer arithmetic I notice that Python wasn't taking advantage of it.

So I tried the following code to see the "explicitly" declaration effect

```
import time

repeat = 1000000

start = time.time()
x = 0
for i in range(repeat):
    x += 1
no_type_time = time.time() - start

start = time.time()
y = int(0)
for i in range(repeat):
    y += 1
int_time = time.time() - start

print('{} - No type'.format(no_type_time))
print('{} - Int'.format(int_time))
```

The code output was the following:

```
0.0692429542542 - No type
0.0545210838318 - Int
```

I assume it has something to do with Python being a dynamic typed language. But when I try to find out the type of the variables, using type(x) and type(y) both output int. Which is curious, because I also ran some tests using x = float(0) and the result is very close to the one with no type "declaration".

I'd like to know why it happens and if possible to get some reference from Python documentation explaining it.

Comment: This is not the way to time execution at all. You should look into `timeit` etc. Anything could have been happening on your system during execution to affect resources.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with explicitly calling `int`; this sounds like you're looking at a confounding factor, like the allocation involved in `range(repeat)` on Python 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the precision on the floats in your `str.format` output (12 significant digits), we can see that you're probably on Python 2.

Python 2 creates an explicit list of a million ints when you run `range(repeat)`, which is slow. It also keeps the memory for all of those ints, so `range(repeat)` is less slow the second time. This is most likely the source of the timing difference, not anything to do with calling `int`.

On Python 2, it is almost always better to use `xrange` instead of `range`. `xrange` generates ints on demand, avoiding the cost in memory and allocation time of generating a whole list up front:

```
for i in xrange(repeat):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you've hit upon OP's problem to a tee.

Comment: Maybe suggest how to fix it with `xrange`?

Comment: This would also explain why proper `timeit` can't repro the problem—each time through the `timeit` loop but the first is reusing memory out of the obheap freelist.

Comment: Assuming OP's results are repeatable (which may or may not be the case), then this should be easily verified by reversing the order of the tests. Also, OP could simply assign the `range(repeat)` to a variable outside of all timing and use that instead.

Comment: @abarnert: `xrange` added.

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce on linux.
Mark that:

• real: The actual time spent in running the process from start to finish, as if it was measured by a human with a stopwatch

• user: The cumulative time spent by all the CPUs during the computation

• sys: The cumulative time spent by all the CPUs during system-related tasks such as memory allocation.

```
→ time python type.py

real    0m0.219s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

→ time python without_type.py

real    0m0.133s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because python caches and reuses some immutable built-in objects, even if they're "stored" as different variables

```
>>> a = 1
>>> id(a)
56188528L
>>> b = int(1)
>>> id(b)
56188528L
```

Python didn't have to allocate any memory or instantiate a new object for the second variable.  It's just reusing the immutable integer object that had already been created.

If you had put your timing tests in different files and ran them separately, or if you had ran the `int(1)` test first, you would have seen different results.

Comment: No. The `x=0` is using a pre-built constant; the `y=int(0)` is using the same constant, and then looking up a global and calling it. There's no reuse there. And besides, allocating memory for a single int is nothing. The problem is the million-item list returned by `range`. It takes a while to build, but it takes even longer to allocate and build. The difference is that the first time, it has to allocate; the second time, there's memory lying around from the list created and then collected before.